# Change a button background while its background is in an animation?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

My button is animated like this:

```
AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.startmain), 1000);
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.startmainan), 1000);

animation.setOneShot(false);

Button imageAnim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

// start the animation!
animation.start();
```

but I want to change its background again when an user presses on it, like in the `xml` of the background:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/kp_p" android:state_pressed= "true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/kp" />
```

but these 2 things won't work together this way, only the animation is doing its work. How can I bring these 2 things together to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead adding background from XML file, add programmatically.

Comment: How to add xml file as a background grammatically?